# Technical name of a particular fountain pen font

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification, symbols, latex

Kind users, I've been trying for two hours to identify a font using the various online tools that can be used in LaTeX but I failed. I don't know if it's even a commercial font.

The `k` that I highlighted with the rectangle color orange, to do a more accurate search, has a very specific name (eg. calligraphic or stylographic + name)? Could someone give me an indication how to direct me for a more targeted search? Thank you all.

[image]

The link of the image is: https://tobiw.de/en/gallery#oscillations-and-waves&gid=3&pid=6 and it is visible also in the related question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501983/to-insert-an-aesthetically-elegant-and-stylish-letter-or-letters-for-mtpro2.

### ADDENDUM:

As by comment of the best user @Bill Kerr I adding the site of the links where I have tried to identify the fonts:

1. https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/;
2. https://www.whatfontis.com/;
3. https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't using the standard TeX Computer Modern font family: it seems to be some kind of Garamond. My guess is that this is either [EB Garamond 12](https://github.com/octaviopardo/EBGaramond12/tree/master/fonts/), or [Adobe Garamond](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/adobe/adobe-garamond-pro), or [Adobe Garamond Premier](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/adobe/garamond-premier-pro), all of which have a standard default italic 'k' that looks just like this.

Comment: @Sebastiano, it's perhaps that you didn't include a link to where this image came from, which can be very helpful (especially when dealing with a poor-quality image like this).

Comment: Kind Copilot into related question there is the link. Now edit my question if this is the problem.

Comment: @Sebastiano - we have special [rules for font ID questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions). That's why you are getting downvotes. (not from me though).  You need to edit your question and provide the missing information.

Comment: @BillyKerr Good afternoon to you and all users. Sincerely as I wrote to Luciano in chat I didn't know that there was a specific question about the destination with the links where to detect the fonts. I connect on some links but I have not succeeded. Now I edit my question and put what I saw. My greetings and thanks.